# Is there an enchanted sword in 3ds terraria?

Tags: terraria-console

I really do not understand what two wikis said. One said that there is not one, and one says that there is an enchanted sword, but no shrines or arkhalis. If so, I want one for my collection.

Answer (score 2):

As detailed on the [Terraria Wiki](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Enchanted_Sword_(item)), the Enchanted Sword does exist in the 3DS version, but the sword shrines do not exist. This means that you can only find the Enchanted Sword stuck in random background rocks (as shown on the wiki page). These rocks are a random spawn anywhere underground.